# How to invoke C# webservice via JavaScript code

Tags: c#, javascript, web-services, titanium

i have Writter a webservice using C#.
I want to invoke these methods from another programming language such as JavaScript.
because I am using `titanium` in my mobile application, but i couldn't find a way to call those methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Titanium its called SOAP, https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/demos/KitchenSink/Resources/examples/soap.js

in here you can define the WDSN url and choose the method you want to call, then you add the parametes.

the results will be recieved as XML file

Answer (score 1):

In [appcelarator](http://appcelerator.com) you can use the `HTTPClient` method

> [Titanium.Network.**HTTPClient**](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.0/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient)

in there example, you change the variable `url` to the endpoint of where is your service and call method. You will receive the incomming data in `this.responseText` variable after the call succeed.